# VSCode Angular 2 final version giving compiling errors

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I just cloned the quickstart project from angular 2 site and just changed app.component.ts to the following:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { 
    private name: string = 'Abc';
    this.name = 'Def';
}
```

VSCode is giving me the following error on using this.name:- 
[ts] Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
any

VSCode version - 1.5.3
Angular 2 Version - 2.0.0 (Final release)

Comment: Why are you trying to reassign `name` in the class body? Did you mean to put it in `constructor`/`ngOnInit`? And what's confused you about the error message?

Comment: Shit.. Did the beginners mistake
thanks a lot for helping